# javascript split string by comma ignore inside quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

i have this string:

`"display, Name" <test@test.com>, display" Name <test@test.com>, test@test.com`

i want to separate this string into an array

```
array[0] = "\"display, Name\" <test@test.com>"
array[1] = "display\" Name <test@test.com>"
array[2] = "test@test.com"
```

here is my code:

```
var comma = inQuotes = false;
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
            if (str[i] == '"') inQuotes = !inQuotes;
            comma = (str[i] == "," && !inQuotes)  ? true : false;
            item += (!comma) ? str[i] : "";
            if(comma || i == str.length-1) {  
                items.push(item);
                item = "";
            }    
        }
```

my problem is that if you have one double quotes without a closer in a string

i appreciate the help...

Comment: Without _some_ form of consistency it's going to be hard. If these followed the email address protocol (`email@address.com`, `name <email@address.com` and `"name" <email@address.com>`) this would be a lot easier. Is it guaranteed to be malformed like you're providing? I stray quote (opening without close or close without opening) is going to make this brutally complex.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: This isn't CSV, it's a list of malformed [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) email addresses.

Comment: I understand. The solution scales nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it working for above string [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtZd6/4/)

```
var a = '"display, Name" <test@test.com>, display" Name <test@test.com>, test@test.com';
var aa = a.match(/"(.*?)"(.*?),|(.*?),|(.*?)$/g); 
aa.pop();
aa // [""display, Name" <test@test.com>,", " display" Name <test@test.com>,", " test@test.com"]
```

Comment: +1 for good bid. My other option was to look-behind for something resembling `email@address.com` or a `>`, but javascript doesn't do look-behinds. I guess ungreedy matching is just as good in this case.

Comment: thanks but its not bullet proof
test it: "display, Name" <test@test.com>, display" Name <test@test.com>, "display, name" <test@test.com>

Comment: @Erana111 how should any programmatic solution know, that quotes number 4 and 5 belong together, and not 3 and 4 (with 5 being unmatched)